# How should I handle POST requests in circuit breaker design pattern?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, circuit-breaker

If downstream microservice is responsible for handling POST request (resource creation) and if it is down then how should I handle this scenario in circuit breaker design pattern?

There could be multiple scenario to address this problem and I am trying to find optimal way of handling this scenario.

1. Should I return dummy response ?
2. What if I don't want my client to POST again in this case and I don't want to loose POST data?

Comment: I really suggest you to read next one article from medium about this topic. [circuit-breaker-pattern](https://medium.com/@emredalc/circuit-breaker-pattern-8a1607b7a4b4). It will give you an overall ideas how to deal with.